# Appropriate Concurrent approach for getting Status number of URL's

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand the concurrent approaches available and trying to know which is more suitable for my current scenario. My work is to get the status of list of URL's whether they return HTTPStatus `OK` or `Not OK` concurrently, limit number of threads and can make sure the provided maximum threads run ALL the times irrespective of batch by batch thread execution. For this, I tried to use Task Parallel Library and it works fine.

**Code**

```
 var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
 {
     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
 };
 Parallel.ForEach(ListMonitorUrl, parallelOptions, i =>
 {
     LogMailError("URL: " + i.URL + " DateTime: " + DateTime.Now + " Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, LogFile);
     VerifyWebAppUrl(i);
 });

  public MonitorURLs VerifyWebAppUrl(MonitorURLs Model)
  {
      List<string> UrlsWithNotOKResponse = new List<string>();

      try
      {
          var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Model.URL);
          using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
          {
              if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && Model.Status == "A")
                  Model.ChangeOfStatus = true;
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && Model.Status != "A")
                  Model.ChangeOfStatus = true;
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Model.ChangeOfStatus = false;
      }
      return Model;
  }
```

I have seen there are other approaches too like `SemaphoreSlim`, `Task`. But I am not sure which is best suited for my scenario. Please suggest.

Comment: _"Please suggest"_ questions are better work on [another site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` is totally unsuited for *IO bound* workloads, you are using up valuable resources waiting around for *IO Completion ports*, and throttling the the *Default Task Scheduler* / *Threadpool* (which will not only bottleneck unnecessarily, it will also starve other parts of your application).

The correct approach will be something that supports the *Async Await Pattern*, like `Task.WhenAll`, *Reactive Extensions*, *TPL DataFlow*, etc.

Here is a simple Microsoft *TPL DataFlow* Example. You can get the nuget here [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/).

The advantages are:

1. It works out of the box with the *Async Await Pattern*
2. You can control the max degrees of parallelism, choose as much as your system/application can handle (this will can be set a lot larger then `Parallel.ForEach`)
3. It's easy to use
4. You can create more complex pipelines of processing when you are ready
5. You wont be throttling the thread-pool, and will be a lot more efficient and performant

**Example**

```
public async List<Model> GetDeadUrls(List<Model> models)
{
   var action = new ActionBlock<Model>(

      // your async method
      model => VerifyWebAppUrl(model),

      //some options
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
      {
         // CancellationToken = sometoken,
         // pick as many as your system can handle
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100,

         // doesn't need to be ordered 
         EnsureOrdered = false,

         // slight performance tweak, there is only one
         SingleProducerConstrained = true  
      });
   
   // start
   foreach (var model in models)
      action.Post(model);
   
   // mark it as completed
   action.Complete();

   // wait for it to finish
   await action.Completion;

   // filter the results
   return models.Where(x => x.ChangeOfStatus).ToList();

}
```

**Async method**

```
public async Task<Model> VerifyWebAppUrl(Model model)
{
   try
   {
      var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(model.URL);
      using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync())
      {
         if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && model.Status == "A")
            model.ChangeOfStatus = true;
         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && model.Status != "A")
            model.ChangeOfStatus = true;
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // this looks suspicious
      model.ChangeOfStatus = false;
   }
   return model;
}
```

***Note** : This is totally untested, and only an example*

Comment: I can now understand the difference between I/O bound and CPU bound operations. How about using Parallel.Foreach with async operation?? Wont that sort out the problem of thread waiting for the I/O opertaion to complete as async can process without expecting the results ??